# While loop not giving desired outcome

Tags: python, while-loop

New to python here, so not sure if I'm posting in the right place but I was wondering why the following loop does not give an answer. I am trying to add all of the numbers previous to i, (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + i), but the loop I came up with does not complete.

```
j = 0
i = 17
while i > 0:
    j = j + i
    i - 1

print(j)
```

I expect j = 153, but the loop doesn't put out anything.

Comment: You've got yourself an infinite loop. i -1 doesn't decrement i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `i`--you're not properly reducing it by 1, so this is an infinite loop. Try this:

```
j = 0
i = 17
while i > 0:
    j = j + i
    i -= 1

print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your line in the while statement, 
i-1, does not assign (= operator) a value to i. i stays 17 forever and ever, and so you see no output because the program gets stuck in your while loop. Try to fix your i assignment, like so:

```
j = 0
i = 17
while i > 0:
    j = j + i
    i = i - 1 # <= i = i - 1

print(j)
```

One way to debug your loop in the future is to put a print statement in the middle, like in the code below. The extra print statements slow your program down a bit, but you'll be able to easily see that your loop is going way more than you want!

```
j = 0
i = 17
while i > 0:
    j = j + i
    i = i - 1
    print(j)
    print(i) # so that we can see that i is going down :P

print(j)
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

- As already stated `i - 1` wasn't assigned back to `i`
- Following is a `pythonic` way of implementing the loop with a `list comprehension`

#### Code:

```py
j = 0
i = 17

j = sum([j + x for x in range(i, 0, -1)])

print(j)

>>> 153
```

#### As a Function:

```py
def sum_of_steps(start: int, stop: int, step: int) -> int:
    return sum([x for x in range(start, stop, step)])


j = sum_of_steps(17, 0, -1)

print(j)

>>> 153
```

- The function, `sum_of_steps` uses [`type hints`](https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/#annotations) or function annotations.
- [Python Basics: List Comprehensions](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-basics-list-comprehensions-631278f22c40)

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, you're not re-assigning to your `i` within the loop. But I'd also note that it's *generally* a bad idea to modify an iterator within the iteration loop. You can achieve the expected results in a more pythonic way using a `range` expression, and wrap it in a function also :)

```
def foo(max_num):
    j = 0
    for i in range(max_num+1):
        j += i
    return j
```

[image]

But even better, **without the loop**:

```
def foo(max_num):
    return sum(range(max_num+1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do what you want to do. The way I recommend you do it is as shown below.

```
total = 0
i = 18
for j in range(i):
  total += j
print(total)
```

The range(i) takes a maximum number i, and allows you to iterate through every number starting from 0 to i-1 (e.g. i = 5 will add numbers 0,1,2,3,4), therefore always make i one more than you need it to be if you want to be if you want to include the max number.